# Manage of server error response with backbone

Tags: backbone.js, error-handling

I would like to know the best way to manage server error response on new, update or delete models. At this moment the server returns a http status code # 400. But the default error handler in Backbone is not showing the errors.

How can i show these errors?

Is it ok that the server returns http error headers when a server side validation fails? (Maybe is better return a success response with a status='ERROR' message)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're returning an http status other than 2XX, you're already half way done with the job. :-) Basically, what you can do is send back anything you want back as the response.

For example, you might just send back something like this:

```
// Send back http status 500
echo 'Could not save, server error';
```

The 500 status will trigger the Backbone error callback and your response is a jqXHR object. In the above example you can get the message by doing something like this in your error callback.

```
model.save({},{
    error: function(model, response) {
        console.log(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

This is the simplest way to get back some data/message about the error that happened server side. You can of course, create more sophisticated data to be returned from the server:

```
// I'm using SLIM RESTful framework...
$dataOut = array('error'=>'Validation type', 'message'=>'Did not validate');
$response->body(json_encode($dataOut));
```

In the same fashion, you can access that response like so:

```
model.save({},{
    error: function(model, response) {
        var responseObj = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
        console.log('Type: ' + responseObj.error + ' Message: ' + responseObj.message);
    }
});
```

Or something along those lines.

Because the response passed into your error callback is the jqXHR object, you have full access to all of its properties that you may want to use:

```
E.g.
response.readyState
response.status
response.statusText // etc.
```

Backbone only needs the http status returned from the server to do its thing.

Comment: I'm facing this issue just today, actually.  Here's the question:  if my SLIM RESTful API is (theoretically) able to be used by clients other than web client (e.g. iOS, etc), then is it okay if SLIM is passing back non-200 HTTP status codes in circumstances like this?  The situations described above (e.g. form validation errors, etc) are arguably not a server error, but rather the server properly responding to bad user input.

Comment: I think your comment is 2 parts. 1) Should SLIM be passing back non-200 http status codes? I would imagine yes as I can't see how it would possible hurt by doing so. A lot of client side stuff relies on that status code to execute success or error callbacks. 2) Is the status 500 appropriate for validation? No. In my example - I just created a problem which was a server one for saving. I guess if you're doing server-side validation, a 400 bad request might be a good choice.

Comment: Not sure I was suggesting 5xx for validation errors, but that's not really the issue.  I think I'm just being a stickler, but server error codes suggest (to me, anyway) that something has gone wrong with the *server*.  A validation error really is the server responding properly to bad data from the *client*.  So at some level, responding with a 4xx to bad client data seems wrong.  However, the whole world is doing it this way, and I'm not about to fight the whole world on that point.  (-;

Comment: I guess I wasn't understanding what you mean. I'm pretty sure your take is much more correct than mine on this. I've read enough of the debate that I'm also not about to fight it one way or another. If Backbone needs a response from the server other than 200 to do it's error callback, I'm going to give it. ;-)